# How to increase the maximum number of grouping levels?

Tags: texlive, grouping

I'm compiling a large, automatically generated LaTeX file that contains many `\[` nested.

This gives the error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
<recently read> \bgroup
```

I don't have a way to reduce the grouping level. The automatically generated file relies on [prooftree.sty by Paul Taylor](http://www.paultaylor.eu/proofs/) --- it is a large derivation tree of 355 levels, and each level needs its own `\[`. On the highest level, this means you have 355 nested `\[`s.

**Is there a way to increase the maximum number of grouping levels?**

I'm using TeX Live 2015 on Debian. I would be okay with recompiling if necessary.

If there are alternatives to `prooftree.sty` that would not need this high grouping levels, I would be interested in that as well.

Comment: Nesting `\[...\]` is completely wrong in the first place.

Comment: Compile with LuaLaTeX

Comment: @egreg I think `prooftree.sty` translates that to `\prooftree` ... `\endprooftree`. LuaLaTeX works, thanks! Perhaps you could make that an answer?

Comment: @egreg -- the documentation for `prooftree` (which *is* on ctan, though not on texlive) says that `\[` *must* be used only within the `prooftree` environment because it is invalid otherwise in latex.  the package hasn't been updated since 1996.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Wow!

Comment: 255 seems rather low, texlive 2014,15,16 have `nest_size = 500         % simultaneous semantic levels (e.g., groups)` in texmf.cnf  (in any case you can increase the number in that file if luatex is not an option )

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks. I have 500 in that file, but changes don't seem to make any difference. I'm editing `/etc/texmf/texmf.cnf` as suggested by `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`. Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  147 (small example, does compile) or 252 (large example, doesn't compile) out of 1000: `34i,147n,56p,4844b,905s stack positions out of 5000i,1000n,10000p,12800000b,80000s` vs. `34i,252n,56p,506b,1401s stack positions out of 5000i,1000n,10000p,12800000b,80000s`. With LuaLaTeX the large example does compile, it uses 537n out of 1000n.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh, sorry, I didn't mention that I had already updated the texmf.cnf to 1000. Also, when I edit it, the values change :-)

Comment: so you mean it works with pdftex now?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no, the 1000 do update, but it still doesn't compile. The quotes from two comments back are the same, but I can change the `1000n` by editing texmf.cnf -- it just doesn't seem to matter for whether I can compile it or not.

Comment: I guess I'm going to give up, I can't debug that at a distance, sorry (you could get @egreg to give a "use luatex" answer and accept that (he needs the points:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand, thanks though. I would accept a LuaLaTeX answer, of course.

Comment: I can't answer; if I do a loop that opens 1024 or more groups, LuaTeX doesn't balk. Whether it works with your monster, I can't know.